# Force cell height to a fixed size

Tags: html, qt

I am not able to fix the cell height to a fixed size. I have this code working on Google Chrome:

```
<html>

<table style='border-spacing: 0px' cellpadding='0'>

    <tr style='height: 10px'>
        <td style='width: 11px; background-image: url(blue_sup_izqu.png)' />
        <td style='width: 9px; background-image: url(blue_sup.png)' />
        <td style='width: 8px; background-image: url(blue_sup_der.png)' />
    </tr>

    <tr style='height: 10px'>
        <td style='width: 11px; background-image: url(blue_izq.png)' />
        <td style='width: 9px; background-color: #23a6eb'>
            <table>
                <td width='100%'>Some text...</td>
                <td>May 2011</td>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td style='width: 8px; background-image: url(blue_der.png)' />
    </tr>

    <tr style='height: 9px'>
        <td style='width: 11px; background-image: url(blue_inf_izqu.png)' />
        <td style='width: 9px; background-image: url(blue_inf.png)' />
        <td style='width: 8px; background-image: url(blue_inf_der.png)' />
    </tr>


</table>

</html>
```

But in the QTextBrowser from Qt I am using it is not working. How can I implement a table with `<div>`'s, for example? How do I put background images to each `<div>`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;overflow:hidden;">
```

or like this:-

```
<style type="text/css">
        #fixedheight {
            table-layout: fixed;
        }

        #fixedheight td {
            height: 20px;
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 25%;
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Please, could you detail how can I use the code you have posted?

Comment: Rahul, where should I use <div>? Where is fixedheight used? your answer is fully uncomplete